# Docker compose already started on windows wake up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using [Docker Destkop](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) under Windows 10.

I use multiples docker-compose files for multiple projects,
and I switch between projects to stop/start some `docker-compose.yml` files depends on my needs.

When I leave my workstation, I put my Windows10 into stand by or shutdown, but when I come back, I always get 2 docker compose actives.

I don't know why they are already started, or where does Docker Destkop retrieve docker container to start ?

I want to retrieve my workstation with zero container running. What should I check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very likely happening because of the `restart` or `restart_policy` setting declared in your docker-compose.yml file (depending on which version of docker-compose you are using). More information can be found in the official documentation. [Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) you can look for the `RESTART_POLICY` section to find out what options there are available for you and what do they mean (or [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#restart) if you are using the older version of docker-compose). While [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) is the description of the arguments you can pass to the `docker run` command.